# Nativescript ScrollView not showing on ios

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have AbsoluteLayout in ScrollView with pager and custom components inside Pager. The code is working on Android, but on iOS is nothing shown. Does anyone have some solution?

```
<ScrollView>
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Pager row="1" #pager [selectedIndex]="currentPagerIndex" width="100%">
        <ns-dashboard-profile height="100" *pagerItem></ns-dashboard-profile>
        <ns-dashboard-home *pagerItem></ns-dashboard-home>
        <ns-dashboard-devices *pagerItem></ns-dashboard-devices>
    </Pager>
    <FlexboxLayout class="navigation-wrapper" top="230">
        <Label text="Profil" (tap)="goToPage('profile')" class="profile-tab"></Label>
        <Label text="Početna" (tap)="goToPage('home')" class="home-tab"></Label>
        <Label text="Moji uređaji" (tap)="goToPage('devices')" class="my-device-tab"></Label>
    </FlexboxLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

ScrollView closing tag is not shown in the code snippet.

Comment: Why you have an absolute layout? ScrollView is generally used as parent for the view you want to be scrollable. If you are expecting flexbox to be scrollable, you should wrap flexbox with scrollview.

Comment: I need Flexbox to have fixed position over tabs, and to be scrollable together with Pager.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, can you share a Playground sample (you may not able to use pager in Playground, but you could replace it with a different view as it's just for debugging)?